# Android 7 TV wireless keyboard language switch not working

Tags: keyboard, 7.0-nougat, android-tv, keyboard-shortcuts

I've got a **Sony X900E TV** model with **Android 7.0** installed, with **Logitech K400 Plus keyboard** connected to it. My issue with them is the fact that it is impossible to switch the language.

The only way to get the language that I need is to go into
`Settings -> Keyboards -> Physical keyboards -> [select language]`, but this cannot even be considered a workaround because these steps are required every time you switch the language, as it only works until you switch the language with `Win+Space`(which actually toggles between virtual keyboards), after which it restores to defaults (**English**) and you have to go through all the steps again.

PS: I've tested the keyboard on **Xiaomi MI5s (Android 6)**, where `Ctrl+Space` works perfectly. Moreover, **Android 6 had the feature to select multiple languages for physical keyboards** and toggle between them, which apparently was removed in Android 7, because you either leave the defaults, or select only 1 specific language.

Is there by any chance a feasible workaround (or maybe a real fix) for this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the answer in installing a separate App called [External Keyboard Helper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apedroid.hwkeyboardhelper) (which has a [pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apedroid.hwkeyboardhelper) and [demo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apedroid.hwkeyboardhelperdemo) version), have set the language switching shortcut in its options and it worked perfectly fine for me.

However, I still consider it a workaround, and that this needed to be a feature implemented into Android 7.